# Микроразметка schema.org. Какой тип целевого объекта допустим для свойства itemReviewed?

Tags: микроразметка

Делаю микроразметку для отзыва обмена валют. Для этого выбрал itemtype Review. Сам сервис обмена обозначен как CurrencyConversionService. Если я ставлю Review как itemprop для CurrencyConversionService - [проверка](http://https/search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) ругается. Если я добавляю к Review itemprop="itemReviewed" itemscope itemtype="schema.org/Service" или itemtype="schema.org/CurrencyConversionService" - тоже ругается "недопустимый тип целевого объекта".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие целевые объекты для itemReviewed?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ не нашёл. Пришлось сервис обмена обозначить как Organization вместо CurrencyConversionService и обойтись без itemReviewed. Похоже это недоработки Google.